# SSRS: Caching a shared Oracle Dataset with date parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

- I am using SSRS (2008R2) to create a large report against an Oracle
  database.
- Because of the size of the report I wanted to cache the shared
  dataset overnight.
- The dataset has a single parameter which should default to today's
  date but be changeable in the report (although this would trigger
  another cache).

I have struggled with this for 3 days and wanted to document how I got it to work, as well as get feedback on my approach.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Oracle Datasource:

- I found that passing parameters to the dataset only worked well for me using the native Oracle drivers, not the OLE DB drivers.

[image: Datasource settings]

### 2. Shared Dataset:

- I was never able to get SSRS to pass a date parameter to Oracle. In my Oracle query I therefore used the conversion `TO_DATE(:EffectiveDate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')` (you'll see why I had to use ISO 8601 format later).
- When adding the variable `:EffectiveDate` to my SQL query a parameter was automatically added to by shared dataset. This initially caused the Oracle error `ORA-01008: not all variables bound`. This was resolved by deleting the dataset parameter and then clicking "refresh fields" on the dataset query screen to re-create it. The only difference apparently being that now the parameter name has a colon.
- I have set the dataset parameter up as shown below in the screenshot:

[image: Shared Dataset Parameter]

- The parameter is of type "text" and defaults to today at midnight in ISO 8601 format (`=Format(Today(),"yyyy-MM-dd\T\0\0:\0\0:\0\0")`)

### 3. Report Dataset:

- The Report Dataset uses the Shared Dataset above and also has a dataset parameter. In this case I want the report dataset parameter to take a date from a report parameter but pass a string to the shared dataset parameter as below:

[image: Report Dataset Parameter]

- The Dataset Parameter is set to the value `=Format(Parameters!EffectiveDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd\T\0\0:\0\0:\0\0")`

### 4. Report Parameter:

- The Report Parameter is set to "date" type as below with a default of `=Today()`:

[image: Report Parameter]
[image: Report Parameter Defaults]

### 5. Shared Dataset Caching:

- First I set the Shared Dataset to use cached data (on the report server via your browser):

[image: Shared Dataset Caching]

- Then I set up a "Cache Refresh Plan":

[image: Cache Refresh Plan]

- The Cache Refresh Plan seems very picky about Parameter format and it was this last step that only seems to work if passing dates as ISO 8601 compliant strings.

### 6. Notes:

- `:EffectiveDate` is the name of my Oracle string bind variable and `EffectiveDate` is the name of my Report parameter. Change your code appropriately.
- I was only interested in the date (i.e. not the time). If you need time as well you may need to make some changes.
- In order to let the end user know how old the data was, I added an extra column `,SYSDATE AS DATA_AGE` to my SQL Query. I was then able to reference the age of the data in my report header with `First(Fields!Report_Date.Value, "<report_dataset_name")`
- I am able to create snapshots of the report but all of the prompts are greyed out, even though all the other prompts only effect report filtering.
- To have different prompt defaults in my snapshots I used the test `IsNothing(User!UserID)`. I'd love to know if there was a better way.
- My example isn't necessarily in the order in which I set things up (i.e. I reference the Report Parameter before showing its setup).